# Creating a Java Combination Lock

Tags: java

I'm working on a computer science assignment, and I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working.

We're supposed to create a combination lock (via a constructor) that prompts the user for letters that spell out the password.

The kicker is that it has to allow the user to make a few mistakes at first. For example, if the password were

D
O
G

the user could type in

A
B
C
D
O
G

And it would unlock the combination lock.

The attached code is probably my... Fifth attempt at this, and i'm not quite sure why it's not working. Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
Code on ideone:

http://ideone.com/D3yFYt

http://ideone.com/jzMNjJ
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you put your code on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am not getting the explanation correctly, so early apologies... But why don't you merge all input and test if the input .endsWith("DOG"). If that's not the point can you list a few more scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at what exactly is in your first String variable. I guess you have a line feed ('\n') at the end of it.

So replace `first.equals(num1)` by `first.startsWith(num1)` and it should work better (untested, might not be the only bug).

Comment: Thanks! That solved the first problem... But now It allows the user to type 

GDA

where the password is DOG. Any other ideas...?